# What are the offroad regulations in UK?

Tags: uk, regulations, motorcycles, off-road

May I ride a motorbike through a non strictly forbidden trail? Do I need some specific permission?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Without specific permission from a land owner the only type of trail you can use is a Byway.  These are strictly speaking roads, but tend to be used primarily for recreation by the public, and are generally maintained as farm tracks.  Some are designated as a restricted byway that do not allow powered vehicles.

Byways are shown on [Ordnance Survey](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/) Explorer maps as a long dashed green line, and as a long pink dashed line on landranger maps.

Comment: Also see Wikipedia entry on [byways in UK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byway_%28road%29).

Comment: Ok, thanks, and is there any map which shows which byways are allowed?

Comment: added details of mapping